# Set class to selected <li> tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was having some troubles when trying to set the on click listerner for `<li>` dynamically. Here is my code to populate the list:

```
for(var i = 0; i < chatlist.length; i++){
        $('<li class="contact"><div class="wrap"><div class="meta"><p class="name">' + contact + '</p><p class="preview">' + preview + '</p></div></div></li>').appendTo($('#contacts ul'));
    }
```

On click listener for selected row:

```
    $('#contacts').on('click', 'li', function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        console.log(index);
   });
```

I am using [this template](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0e3Ma). Upon selecting row, I wanted to set the selected `<li>` tag to

```
<li class = 'contact active'></li>
```

I managed to get the selected row index but I not sure how to set the HTML class for selected `<li>`. Any idea?

Comment: Can't you just `$(this).addClass("active")` in the `<li>` listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I managed to get the selected row index but I not sure how to set the
>   HTML class for selected `<li>`. Any idea?

You can just `addClass` on the `click` event itself

```
$('#contacts').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $( "#contacts li" ).removeClass( "active" ); //assuming that it has to be removed from other li's, else remove this line
    $( this ).addClass( "active" );
});
```

Comment: Hey any ideas on how to set the addClass() to first li item only?

Comment: You can use `:first` selector.

Comment: Hey is there any way to set the li to active class based on an index rather than the first one?

Comment: Yes, try `eq` selector.

Answer (score 1):

try this code which add active class and also i add css to check different

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.list li').click(function() {
             $( '.list li' ).removeClass( "active" ); // remove active class from all li 
            $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class for click li
        });
    });
```

```css
.active {
color:red;
}
   li {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
            <li>Test 5</li>
            <li>Test 6 </li>
            <li>Test 7</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the click event handler, `$(this)` will point to the `li` element which was clicked. So you should be able to assign a class to it like this:

```
$('#contacts').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected"); // Assign the class here
  var index = $(this).index();
  console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your jquery logic in such a way that will remove the `active` class from all `li` inside `contacts` id and then add the `active` class to the `li` that has been clicked which you can get from the `index` of the `li` like:

```
var clickedLi = $('#contacts ul li')[index];
```

or use `$(this)` instead. Please check the attached snippet.

```js
var chatlist = new Array(3);
var contact = 'contact';
var preview = 'preview';
for(var i = 0; i < chatlist.length; i++){
    $('<li class="contact"><div class="wrap"><div class="meta"><p class="name">' + contact + '</p><p class="preview">' + preview + '</p></div></div></li>').appendTo($('#contacts ul'));
}

$('#contacts').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
     $('#contacts ul li').each(function(){
       $(this).removeClass('active');
     });
    
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
.active{
color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contacts">
   <ul>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add active class like this :

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```